# Python: Storing a dictionary in more than one json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'ahik': [2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1], 'tyeo': [5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2], 'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1]....}
```

As the dictionary is very large I want to store it in two json file both having a part of the dictionary(lets say 50%). Also, How to retrieve it once I store it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways to split a dict. Here's one.

```
from itertools import islice

spam = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5'}
spam1, spam2 = [dict(islice(spam.items(), i, None, 2)) for i in (None, 1)]
print(spam1, spam2)  # {'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'e': '5'} {'b': '2', 'd': '4'}
```

We could have converted the items to a tuple and used a regular slice, but since your dict is "very large", it's probably better to use `islice`.

`import json` then you can use `json.dump()` to save a dict into a file, and `json.load()` to get a dict back from the file.

To merge the two dicts, use `dict.update()`

```
spam1.update(spam2)
print(spam1)  # {'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'e': '5', 'b': '2', 'd': '4'}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert your dictionary into list of key and values, then split them and dump in to two different files,

```
import json
d = {'ahik': [2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1], 'tyeo': [5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2], 'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1]}
dlist=list(d.items())
with open("firsthalf.txt","w") as df1, open("secondhalf.txt","w") as df2:
    json.dump(dict(dlist[:len(d)//2]),df1)
    json.dump(dict(dlist[len(d)//2:]),df2)
```

now it stored our dictionary in to two files as two half dictionaries, now to retrieve them from those two files we have to load and merge those two dictionaries.

```
with open("firsthalf.txt","r") as df1, open("secondhalf.txt","r") as df2:
    fh,sh=json.load(df1),json.load(df2)
mydict = fh.copy()
mydict.update(sh)
print(mydict)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'abc': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1], 'tyeo': [5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2], 'ahik': [2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1]}
```

Comment: write/dumps is redundant when you could just dump. Same with loads/read. Just load.